# Java EJB, conceptos

Tags: java, spring, ejb

¿Alguien puede aclararme ciertos conceptos?

- Un EJB, ¿es una clase Java específica del framework EJB?
- ¿EJB es un framework al igual que pueden serlo Struts, o Spring? o ¿realmente un EJB es un tipo de clases java independientemente del framework que utilizo?

¡¡Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Un EJB es una interfaz para construir aplicaciones web que forma parte de JavaEE, Java Enterprise Edition que es un sistema de construccion de aplicaciones web en entornos empresariales y sistemas distribuidos. Esto resumiendo un poco, más información:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans[EJB: Entrerprise JavaBeans](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Jose

Comment: Eso creo que se agradece votando...si no me equivoco.